# How to open window but show it below my splash screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, startup

I have the following logic in my App.xaml.cs.  First, the splash screen is shown while some initialization is done.  At a certain point, I have initialized enough in order to show my main application window.  However, I want the splash screen to continue to show until all of the needed data is cached.  The problem I have is that when I show the main window, it always gets shown on top of the splash screen.  I've tried to set the ShowActivated property to false on the main window before showing but it still is shown over the splash screen.  Any ideas?

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnStartup(e);

  _splashWindow = new SplashWindow();

  _splashWindow.Show();

  ...

  _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
  _mainWindow.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
  _mainWindow.ShowActivated = false;
  _window.Show();
}

private void OnCacheLoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _splashWindow.Close();
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
  _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
  _mainWindow.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
  _window.Show();
  _splashWindow.TopMost = true;
  _splashWindow.Owner = _window;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
_splashWindow.Owner = _window;
```

After the call to `_window.Show()` ?

Comment: When I do that, the main window still gets drawn over the splash window.  Although, there is only one taskbar item (which is also something I wanted).  If I click on the taskbar item after the main window is shown, the splash screen comes back to the top.  But, I'd like it to always remain on top while displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Is there not a `TopMost` property you can set?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

There's some good stuff in there. Looks like you should set TopMost as well as ownership.